# How to take expectation of a hierarchical model?

Tags: statistics

If I have a hierarchical model, where
$$
X \sim Bin(n, p)
$$
$$
p \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)
$$
Can I say that $\mathbf{E}[x] = n\mathbf{E}(p) = n\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}$?

It seems not, then how should I get the expectation in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Comment: You are correct. This is because of the [tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) - for any pair of random variables $X,Y,$ it holds that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[ \mathbb{E}[X|Y] ]$ (note that the inner expectation is the conditional expectation given $Y$. For a proof, think of Fubini's theorem). Now, $\mathbb{E}[X|p] = np,$ and so $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[np] = \cdots$

Comment: You are looking at a [Beta-binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution) compound distribution.